# Slow C# websockets on asp.net javascript angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, websocket

This is my first question.
I am trying to build a websocket server that can handle 50-100 concurrent users and send 50 messages per second.
On my dev machine it works for one user but when uploaded on the server it slows down more and more depending on the users.
Thanks for your time.

superwebsocket code sample:

```
public class SuperWs
{
    WebSocketServer server;
    WebSocketSession[] array = new WebSocketSession[100];
    public SuperWs()
    {
        server = new WebSocketServer();
        server.Setup(new ServerConfig
        {
            Port = 23023,
            Name = "super web socket",
            LogAllSocketException = true,
            LogBasicSessionActivity = true,
        });
        server.NewSessionConnected += NewSessionConnected;
        server.NewMessageReceived += NewMessageReceived;
        server.SessionClosed += SessionClosed;
        server.Start();

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (array[j] != null)
                            array[j].Send(string.Format("Hello! ms: {0}, mes: {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, i));
                    }
                }
                sw.Stop();
            }
        });
    }

    private void SessionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseReason value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", session.SessionID, value);
    }

    void NewMessageReceived(WebSocketSession session, string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", session.SessionID, value);
    }

    private int count;
    private void NewSessionConnected(WebSocketSession session)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(session);
        array[count++] = session;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the configuration of your server where you have hosted this app and if you could post your code along that shall be helpful to see how you are connecting ??

Answer (score 1):

First, when client and server are not in the same machine (like in your DEV environment), network will cause some delay. If you have 'n' clients connected, it will take 'n * delay' to send a message to all nodes. You should create a different loop per session, so basically on `NewSessionConnected` create a new loop that sends 50 messages each second and ends when the session is disconnected (rather than `while(true)`).

If you are going to have that parallel work, you should use `async` programming and use `await Task.Delay(1000)` rather than `Thread.Sleep(1000)`, since the latest will block the thread, where the previous will allow the thread to go and do something else in the mean time. Unfortunately SuperWebSocket does not support `async` programming.

Pseudo-code:

```
private async void NewSessionConnected(WebSocketSession session)
{
    while (session.IsConnected)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000 / 50);
        session.Send("Hello");
    }
}
```

Also, you have to start thinking what are you going to do when nodes disconnect :)

As a side note, I develop a [WebSocket framework that supports async programming](http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/), that amount of traffic [should be no problem](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/WebSocketListener-performance-tests).